# Trying to implement an external Java interface in Nativescript Android Plugin

Tags: angular, nativescript

I am trying to use an interface from this library in a NativeScript Android Angular application.

The library is : https://github.com/begeekmyfriend/yasea

The code is as follows:

```
@Interfaces([net.ossrs.yasea.SrsRecordHandler.SrsRecordListener])
export class MyComponent extends Common implements net.ossrs.yasea.SrsRecordHandler.SrsRecordListener 
{
```

The above gives me the error "cannot find namespace net"

I have included external libraries before so I know where to put the aar in the folder structure. I can call other functions like so:

```
declare var com: any;
declare var android: any;
declare var java: any;
declare var net: any;

let SrsCameraView = net.ossrs.yasea.SrsCameraView;
let SrsPublisher = net.ossrs.yasea.SrsPublisher;

 @Interfaces([net.ossrs.yasea.SrsRecordHandler.SrsRecordListener])
 export class MyComponent extends Common implements net.ossrs.yasea.SrsRecordHandler.SrsRecordListener 
 {
 
 public createNativeView(): Object {


 // the following works without errors
this._mCameraView = new SrsCameraView(androidApp.context);
this._mPublisher = new SrsPublisher(this._mCameraView);

...
return this._mCameraView;
}
```

Is there something I am missing because I am trying to set up an interface with a net.X.X instead of com.X.X?

The interface is definitely in that namespace.

The error is a compile time error. This is the error that is returned:

```
mycomponent.android.ts:60:46 - error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'net'.

60 export class MyComponent extends Common implements net.ossrs.yasea.SrsRecordHandler.SrsRecordListener {
                                                ~~~

mycomponent.android.ts:60:46 - error TS4019: Implements clause of exported class 'Wowza' has or is using private name 'net'.

60 export class MyComponent extends Common implements net.ossrs.yasea.SrsRecordHandler.SrsRecordListener {
```

Thanks!!

Comment: Is it a runtime error or TS compile time error? Please post complete error log. Also is `MyComponent` extending NativeScript View? if Yes, then it may not be right. It's not a native object, you are trying to combine native class definition with JS one.

Comment: I edited my post and added in the error. The error is a compile time error. MyComponent is extending a NativeScript View -- 'tns-core-modules/ui/core/view';

Comment: You can not use `declare var net: any` with interface. The whole purpose of interface is only to make sure the typings are strictly followed. Either you have to add typings for the native interface Or simply remove `implements` statement as `@Interfaces` is the one actually matters here. Also as I mentioned already you can implement native interface on non native object. You define a standalone class that implements the `SrsRecordHandler` interface and create an instance, store the reference of the same in your component.